# Using javascript to serve smaller images with DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, seo, google-search-console, pagespeed, domcontentloaded

I am fairly new to JavaScript and have been trying to come up with a script of my own to dynamically serve smaller images to users on mobile devices.

Lets say I have a normal HTML image as follows:

```
<img id="test" src="https://www.example.com/pictures/myimage.jpg" />
```

I have then come up with a simple script that checks the page dimensions BEFORE any images are loaded (by using the DOMContentLoaded event). Depending on the incoming screen dimensions, it alters the image src to serve an image that is optimised to that screen size. This is the script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){

var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

if(x >= 1000)
{
var largeImage = true;
}

else if(x <= 999 && x >= 651)
{
var mediumImage = true;
}

else if(x <= 650)
{
var smallImage = true;
}

if(largeImage){
// Do nothing as the image is the right size (large)
}

if(mediumImage){
var imageSrc = document.getElementById("test").src.toString();
document.getElementById("test").src = imageSrc.replace("/myimage.jpg","/medium/myimage.jpg");
}

if(smallImage){
var imageSrc = document.getElementById("test").src.toString();
document.getElementById("test").src = imageSrc.replace("/myimage.jpg","/small/myimage.jpg");
}
});
```

Apologies for the horribly hacked up code, but it does actually work and saves a not inconsequential 2% on load times for mobile devices.

However, when I analyse the results using Google Page Speed Insights, I see that the page is still loading the original image (albeit somehow at a very small size, usually a few hundred bytes), as well as the smaller 'replacement' image as well. So my question is how is the original image being loaded, since my understanding of DOMContentLoaded is as follows:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
>   and subframes to finish loading

(taken from MDN)

And I know it's not really relevant to the question, but if anyone also has an SEO background, it would be useful to know if this kind of behaviour is damaging in any way from an SEO standpoint.

I would prefer to stick with JavaScript (as opposed to using JQuery), as a big part of this is about trying to learn the language and come up with something genuinely useful myself.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely to do with the browser prefetch I suspect. If there is a src on the image tag then it'll take load time regardless. Any of the js solutions I've seen for responsive images have empty/dummy src tags and then the appropriate img src gets swapped in.

I quite like this uncomment technique too as a js option. If the original tag is commented then nothing will get loaded, then you only uncomment the one you need (based on your existing work) https://github.com/DSGNRSteve/Uncomment-Technique-for-RWD

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I suspected as much. I looked into using an empty src tag, however this causes the page to fail the W3C compliance test :)

Instead, I'm going down the route of generating the entire image element with JS, so there then is nothing for the browser to prefetch. Coupled with <noscript> to serve a default image when JS is turned off (or in the case of certain search engine spiders that do not execute JS) I think this may solve my problem. Still not sure if this would have a negative SEO impact however...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, this is the final code I have been using for a while. If you compress and reduce the size of mobile images, you can save around 15% on each image, and this is certainly reflected in the Google page speed score.

```
enter code here
<?php

// This function generates images of the correct dimensions for the 
//device viewing them, to save on bandwidth

// It takes the following parameters:
// 1. The name of the container in which the image will be placed
// 2. The src of the larger image
// 3. The src of the smaller image (note this is also used as the
//default image if JS is 
// turned off, see the <noscript> tag at the bottom
// 4. The image class
// 5. The image alt text

function generate_image($image_container_name, $big_image, 
$small_image, $image_class, $image_alt){
?>


<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){

var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;

if(x >= 651){
var largeImage = true;
}

else if(x <= 650){
var smallImage = true;
}

if(largeImage){
var myImage = document.createElement("img");

myImage.setAttribute("src", "<?php echo $big_image; ?>");
myImage.setAttribute("class", "<?php echo $image_class; ?>");
myImage.setAttribute("alt", "<?php echo $image_alt; ?>");

var element = document.getElementById("<?php echo 
$image_container_name; ?>");
element.appendChild(myImage);

}

if(smallImage){

var myImage = document.createElement("img");

myImage.setAttribute("src", "<?php echo $small_image; ?>");
myImage.setAttribute("class", "<?php echo $image_class; ?>");
myImage.setAttribute("alt", "<?php echo $image_alt; ?>");

var element = document.getElementById("<?php echo 
$image_container_name; ?>");
element.appendChild(myImage);

}

});


</script>

<div id="<?php echo $image_container_name; ?>"></div>

<noscript>

<img src="<?php echo $small_image; ?>" class="<?php echo $image_class;
?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>" />

</noscript>

<?php

}

?>
```